# Retrieve a limited number of database notifications in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel database notifications, every time a user make an action a new notification will be saved in the notifications table.
If i want to get all notifications i use this line of code

```
Auth::user()->notifications
```

Everything is working fine.. however what if i want to limit the selection to only the first 10 notification instead of getting all ?

Using Mysql its very easy by running this command

```
SELECT * FROM notifications LIMIT 5
```

But how can i achieve this using Laravel notification methods ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only first N notifications of a user then you can do:

```
Auth::user()->notifications()->limit(N)->get();
```

But if you want to get N notifications (not just for the current user) i.e. execute something akin to `SELECT * FROM notifications LIMIT 5` you need to do:

```
Notification::limit(N)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

```
auth()->user()->notifications()->latest()
->paginate(N)
```